# Facing this issue in Next js: TypeError: __webpack_require__.nmd is not a function, when i deployed on aws, and slow loading of webpack-hmr

Tags: reactjs, performance, next.js, slowdown

In NextJS, I am facing issue this
"TypeError: **webpack_require**.nmd is not a function",

it only happens on the server, but on local, I am not getting this error. I have noted two things during facing this issue.

- webpack-hmr taking too much time to load almost 45 sec in local, but when it comes on the server, its status remains pending for so long.
- When I see in the network, this.
  "_app.js?ts=1680289247269"
  chunks data takes so much time to load almost 65mb data.

  I am using MUI5, and when the website loads for the first time, it lands on the login page.

  On local, I am facing one more issue when the first time login page loads; it loads between 45       sec - 65 sec.

  I tried to change my next.config file, but still getting this error and slow loading of the login page.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this is a permanent solution, but I came across this problem today -  restarting the dev server worked for me (re-running `npm run dev`).

Comment: I tried it, not work for me, but it's not about starting the local server again, it happens whenever page load first time

Comment: What's your next version? Have you tried bumping to latest